# Curl POST request into python code

Tags: python, curl

Currently I have the following code. It is working, but not exactly as I need. I need to get json content from the reply, just one parameter.

```
url = 'https://somelinkhere/get_info'
data = {'auth_info':'{"session_id":"blablablaidhere"}', 'params':'{"id":"12345"}'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
res = response.content
print res
```

Now it returns

```
'�Z[o�6�+���֖���ې�0�{h�`
                        AK�M�"����o�9�dI���t��@RI<��"�GD�D��.3MDeN��
                                                                           ��hͣw�fY)SW����`0�{��$���L��Zxvww����~�qA��(�u*#��݅Pɣ����Km���' 
etc.
```

What i need is to output res['balance_info']['balance']

Comment: `requests` is not standard lib.

Comment: curl converter: https://shibukawa.github.io/curl_as_dsl/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally, -d would become `data=...` in requests. You `curl` data includes the `auth_info` and `params` as things sent to the server and perhaps would be better understood if you quoted the whole thing, e.g. `-d 'auth_info={"session_id":"blablablaidhere"}'`

Translating that into python:

```
data = {'auth_info':'{"session_id":"blablablaidhere"}',
        'params':'{"id":"12345"}'})
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Which would yield:

```
send: b'POST /get_info HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: somelinkhere\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.12.3\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Length: 92\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n'
send: b'auth_info=%7B%22session_id%22%3A%22blablablaidhere%22%7D&params=%7B%22id%22%3A%2212345%22%7D'
```